# ng-bind-html doesn't work with CaseComponent.CommentBody

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript, angularjs, angular

Could anyone please help me figure out why `ng-bind-html` doesn't work with `CaseComponents.CommentBody`?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="ticketComment in modalObject.Case.CaseComments">
            <td >
                <span style="label-value" ng-bind="ticketComment.CreatedBy.Name"></span>
                <p style="label-value" ng-bind="ticketComment.CreatedDate | date:'medium'"></p>
            </td>
            <td style="max-width: 400px; word-wrap: break-word;"><div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(ticketComment.CommentBody)"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

In my angular controller, I have

```
$scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
        testing = "<h1><div style='color:red'> Tranzact Tickets</div> <h1> <br />"
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
    }
```

Everything worked perfectly except the ng-bind-html doesn't seem to insert the ticketComment.CommentBody as HTML which has elements like `<br />` but it outputs as string `"Hello <br /> We will contact you as soon as possible <br /> IT"`.

I even tried to create a variable called testing and the function `trustedHtml()` did return testing as HTML.

I am thinking maybe CommentBody is not string or ng-bind-html just doesn't work well with ng-repeat?